# Why int.__mro__ doesn't contain numbers.Integral?

Tags: python

I expected isinstance function to return True only for types that exist in object's type mro tuple. But:

```
>>> isinstance(int(), numbers.Integral)
True
>>> int.__mro__
(<type 'int'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Why int.**mro** does not contain numbers.Integral?

Comment: I don't know the internals enough to point at something, but generally the objects implemented in C for speed bypass some things

Comment: Why should it?  `numbers.Integral` is for defining the interface, that doesn't mean it needs to be in the `int` mro.

Comment: `int` isn't a descendent of `Integral` in the normal sense, but only because `Integral.__subclasshook__`  is implemented to make it *look* like it is.